# My va_start/va_end macroses work wrong

Tags: c++, function, macros

everyone;

Please help me with this:

```
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "stdarg.h"
using namespace std;

void f(char a,...)
{
    cout<<a;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list,a);
    cout<<va_arg(list,char)<<" ";
    va_end(list);
};

int main()
{
    f('a','b','c','d');
    system("pause >> void");
    return 0;
}
```

It must give as result this

```
a b c d
```

But it gaves only

```
a b
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is using `va_args` in C++. If you're a self learner, stop right now because it's not useful (there is a slight chance you might stumble upon having to use it at some point, but you might as well learn then). If you're learning this at a college or something tell your prof to stop teaching you garbage.

Comment: 'it' in the above comment referring to `va_args`, not C++. I'm not sure if that was obvious from the sentence structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

Passing `char` into a varargs function gets promoted to `int` at least on some compilers. I'd forgotten about this one myself until I banged out a bit of test code and the compiler nagged. That means your 8 bits just became, most likely, 32 or 64 bits. This can cause a pretty good **Kaboom!**

And

```
cout<<va_arg(list,char)<<" ";
```

Each call to va_arg is going to return one variable, the character 'b' in this case. To get the 'c' you'll have to call it again. Etc...

This leaves you with the interesting problem of knowing when to stop calling va_arg.

Here's a cheap hack:

```
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "stdarg.h"
using namespace std;

void f(char a,...)
{
    cout<<a;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list,a);
    char ch = (char)va_arg(list,int);
    while (ch != '\0') // stopping on null
    {
        cout << " " << ch; // cout << a didn't have a space appended so I 
                           // reversed the placement here
        ch = (char)va_arg(list,int);
    }
    va_end(list);
};

int main()
{
    f('a','b','c','d', '\0');  // note the added null. 
    cout << endl;

    system("pause >> void"); // better ways to do this cin >> junk, for one
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Passing char into a varargs function gets promoted to int at least on some compilers." `s/some/all conforming/`. This is required by the standard, and known as the *default argument promotions*.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming. Suspected that would be the case for portability if nothing else, but wasn't sure.